# How to match a string with pythons regex with optional character, but only if that optional character is preceded by another character

Tags: python, regex

I need to match a string that optionally ends with numbers, but only if the numbers aren't preceded by a 0.

so AAAA should match, AAA1 should, AA20 should, but AA02 should not.

I can figure out the optionality of it, but I'm not sure if python has a "preceded by" or "followed by" flag.

```
if s.isalnum() and re.match("^[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*$", s):
        return True
```

Comment: Another idea by use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`^[A-Z]+(?!0)\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pNprm8/1) (Just to mention, prefer selected answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^[A-Z]+(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/IZcwuv/1)

---

`^[A-Z]+` - match letters from the beginning of string

`(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?` - optionally match a number that doesn't start from `0`

`$` - end of string

Comment: AA3209 should not be match according to the OP.  Also, your pattern does not match A000, which, in the absence of more info, should also be a match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - you seem to "understand" this much differently than the rest of us.